# Concatenate Pivot Tables in Python to put column titles in list if they have 1

Tags: python, concatenation

This is probably a simple question but I was just wondering if there is a Python code where if I have a pivot table that has textbook ISBNs and the associated states that are used in for school (0 being not used and 1 being used), is there a way to get these states (with 1s) in a list assocated with this ISBN?

Thank you!

[what I have and what I want from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Jho.png)

not sure how to tackle this one

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.